# C# LoadFile font and formatting

Tags: c#, file-io, fonts, formatting

How can I load a file in a c# app so that I can see it formatted.

If I use:

```
richTextBox2.LoadFile("a.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

I did it with:

```
textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("a.txt");
```

The text is not formatted at all, new lines and CR's are totally missing, also the tabs

also the file open ok in notepad, but it opens bad in wordpad

Can I load the file in a textbox? (use multi-line)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried loading it as RichText?

```
richTextBox2.LoadFile("a.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Comment: Change the file type from a .txt to .rtf

Comment: i did it with `textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("a.txt");`